# Matplotlib: Draggable is not working on multiple legends of plots which are generated with twinx()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have two legends, as below, I find that I can't drag the first legend, what is the problem? how to deal with it? thanks!

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    ax1.plot([1,2,3],[0.1,0.82,0.3],'y*', label="one")
    ax2.plot([1,2,3],[5,6,7],'ro', label="two")

    leg1 = ax1.legend()
    leg2 = ax2.legend()

    leg1.draggable(state=True)
    leg2.draggable(state=True)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general limitation of twinned axes.  Pick events are limited to the "top" axes.

There are a handful of reasons for this, but it basically boils down to "it takes a good deal of refactoring to change, might break backwards compatibility in a subtle way, and it only impacts a few things".

There is a workaround, but it's a touch clunky.  I'll also move the second legend from on top of the first. Otherwise, we'll just be dragging both of them at once.  Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Workaround(object):
    def __init__(self, artists):
        self.artists = artists
        artists[0].figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        for artist in self.artists:
            artist.pick(event)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot([1,2,3],[0.1,0.82,0.3],'y*', label="one")
ax2.plot([1,2,3],[5,6,7],'ro', label="two")

leg1 = ax1.legend()
leg2 = ax2.legend(loc='upper left')

leg1.draggable(True)
leg2.draggable(True)

draggable_workaround = Workaround([leg1, leg2])

plt.show()
```